# How to find the two solutions in a domain?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve 
cos(x)=0.8 and want to get the two solutions which are in [0,2 pi).

How to do this in Mathematica?

I tried

```
Solve[Cos[x]==0.8,x,{0,2*Pi}]
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
NSolve[{Cos[x] == 0.8, 0 <= x <= 2*Pi}, x]
```

> {{x -> 0.643501}, {x -> 5.63968}}

Answer (score 2):

Plotting the function will give you some idea, where the roots could be,

```
Plot[Cos[x] - 0.8, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Now providing some rough guesses in the view of the above plot,

```
FindRoot[Cos[x] == 8/10, {x, {0.2, 5}}]
```

> {x -> {0.643501, 5.63968}}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`, you can do

```
Solve[Cos[x]==8/10 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get Numerical value, now apply `N`

```
 N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]